# How to Derive/Calculate Upper/Lower Corner in GML Envelope with XSL from PosList XML

Tags: xslt, gml

Seeking advice on how to calculate the lowerCorner and upperCorner in GML Envelope given an array (coordinates) in the XML.  Note I have reduced the list of coordinates significantly to keep short.

Aware I need to iterate the `<coordinates>` element but unsure most efficient way to calculate the lowerCorner and upperCorner pairs to eventually map into the GML Envelope.

XML Sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Extract>
    <n1:XMLExtract xmlns:n1="urn:com:aaa">
        <regionId>4671</regionId>           
        <coordinates>151.344553 -33.4123250000193, 151.346606 -33.4126370000193, 151.347188 -33.4127280000193, 151.347707 -33.4127990000193, 151.347858 -33.4121160000193, 151.34931 -33.4123270000192, 151.349253 -33.4125910000192, 151.349693 -33.4126610000193, 151.34963 -33.4129810000192, 151.351338 -33.4132280000193, 151.351393 -33.4129550000193, 151.352038 -33.4130480000192, 151.352169 -33.4128100000193, 151.352355 -33.4128370000193, 151.35249 -33.4128910000193, 151.352585 -33.4129170000193, 151.352913 -33.4130080000193, 151.35294 -33.4131310000193, 151.355307 -33.4134860000192, 151.355315 -33.4134470000193, 151.355764 -33.4135020000193, 151.355757 -33.4135590000193, 151.356196 -33.4136240000192, 151.356229 -33.4134890000192, 151.356342 -33.4136260000193, 151.358407 -33.4139280000192, 151.358335 -33.4142510000192, 151.358465 -33.4143660000193, 151.359572 -33.4145260000194, 151.359936 -33.4144860000193, 151.360146 -33.4146080000193, 151.360627 -33.4146790000192, 151.360619 -33.4146980000193, 151.362603 -33.4149980000193, 151.362996 -33.4150940000193, 151.363655 -33.4158080000193, 151.364236 -33.4161380000194, 151.365691 -33.4163460000193, 151.366212 -33.4164920000193, 151.367333 -33.4170870000193, 151.368456 -33.4180250000193, 151.368481 -33.4180200000193, 151.368888 -33.4183130000193, 151.371305 -33.4187840000193, 151.373106 -33.4187890000193, 151.374004 -33.4189970000194, 151.374994 -33.4194460000193, 151.376513 -33.4199650000193, 151.378063 -33.4197680000193, 151.379519 -33.4185780000193, 151.383555 -33.4161210000193, 151.393929 -33.4059400000192, 151.396063 -33.4062720000193, 151.396727 -33.4051740000192, 151.39785 -33.4032380000193, 151.397122 -33.4027200000192, 151.396761 -33.4022700000193, 151.396541 -33.4008350000192, 151.397496 -33.3995910000192, 151.397788 -33.3990280000193, 151.397788 -33.3990100000192, 151.397773 -33.3990000000192, </coordinates>
        <interactionId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
        <interactionTypeId xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
        <refNumber/>
        <incidentNumber/>
        <payloadId>20002065</payloadId>
        <filename/>
        <url/>
    </n1:XMLExtract>
</Extract>
```

Desired output as follows:

```
<gml:boundedBy>
  <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="EPSG:4283">
    <gml:lowerCorner>-30.511985 151.63592</gml:lowerCorner>
    <gml:upperCorner>-30.49207 151.669169</gml:upperCorner>
  </gml:Envelope>
</gml:boundedBy>
```

Comment: **1.** Could you provide a definition of "lowerCorner" and "upperCorner"? How would one find these if doing this manually? **2.** Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Hi Michael, no support for XSLT 2.0 unfortunately.  As for a definition of lowerCorner and upperCorner these are GML specs (so there is likely a math function to achieve this).  I did locate the following definition '‘An envelope is a rectangle defined using two points (lower-left and upper-right) whose sides are parallel to the coordinate system axes’'

Comment: I would like to help you with the XSLT, without having to learn GML in the process. The coordinates you show as the expected output do not appear in your input. Even if they did, I would not know how to identify them.

Comment: P.S. Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using? I suspect you could really use some extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the coordinates of the rectangle bounding your polygon, and assuming your processor supports the EXSLT extension functions `str:split()`, `math:min()` and `math:max()` (IOW, you are using either libxslt or Xalan), you could do something like:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:n1="urn:com:aaa"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl math str"
exclude-result-prefixes="n1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Extract">
    <xsl:variable name="vertices-rtl">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:split(n1:XMLExtract/coordinates, ', ')">
            <v x="{substring-before(., ' ')}" y="{substring-after(., ' ')}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vertices" select="exsl:node-set($vertices-rtl)/v" />

    <output>
        <lowerLeft>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:min($vertices/@x)" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:min($vertices/@y)" />
        </lowerLeft>
        <upperRight>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:max($vertices/@x)" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="math:max($vertices/@y)" />
        </upperRight>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <lowerLeft>151.344553 -33.4199650000193</lowerLeft>
  <upperRight>151.39785 -33.3990000000192</upperRight>
</output>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, great thanks this is calculating, I'm just asking the Spatial gurus to validate the values are correct!  They do have an Oracle Spacial lib that can validate for us.  Yes I was trying to avoid getting too deep into GML also due to time constraints.  Thanks again, much appreciated!